# How to find neighbor element of array 1 from reverse of the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, element, neighbours

```
function compareNumbers(x, y) {
return x - y;
}  
var a = [3,6,2,7,8,10,43] //I have one array
var b = a.slice().sort(compareNumbers).reverse(); //I reverse this array
```

//Now I have 2 arrays

```
a = [3,6,2,7,8,10,43]
b = [43, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2]
```

My Question: I want to find the neighbour element of b in array a.
For example:

b[0] that is 43 , want to find both neighbour of 43 in array a. // 10

b[1] that is 10 , want to find both neighbour of 10 in array a. // 43,8

b[6] that is 2, want to find both neighbour of 2 in array a. // 6,7

Comment: is it really even necessary to search the reversed array? the neighbors will always be the same - just a reversed order.

Comment: They won't be the same. Look at the neighbours of 3.

Comment: It is not same because I sort that array first and then reversed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a loop of the array and then check if it can have the left or right neighbour or not, if it has get it and if it doesn't leave that neigbour. For example if the loop is the first then there would be no left neighbor in that case leave the left_neigbour and if the loop is last than there will be no right neigbour in that case leave the right one  and get the left_neighbour.Just use the below code

```
a = [3,6,2,7,8,10,43];
    b = [43, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2];
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var left_neighbour = '';
        } else {
            var left_neighbour = a[i - 1];
        }
        if (i == b.length) {
            var right_neighbour = '';
        } else {
            var right_neighbour = a[i + 1];
        }
        if (left_neighbour !== '') {
            if (right_neighbour) {
                console.log(left_neighbour + "," + right_neighbour);
            } else {
                console.log(left_neighbour);
            }
        } else {
            if (right_neighbour) {
                console.log(right_neighbour);
            } else {
                console.log(left_neighbour);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3vvba58/1/

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it still didnt solve my purpose. I want neighbour of Array a with correspondence to array b.

Comment: @user3342244 Updated my answer... Have a look at it again. http://jsfiddle.net/r3vvba58/1/ . If its in reverse order decrement the value and change the loop accordingly

Answer (score 2):

If one of the neighbours doesn't exist you will get `null`.

```
var searchvalue = b[0]
var index = a.indexOf(searchvalue)

var firstNeighbour = index > 0 ? a[index-1] : null
var secondNeighbour = index < (a.length - 1) ? a[index + 1] : null
```

Comment: As simple as it get's.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo thanks for fixing my `indexOf` :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the need of the second array and for a comfortable data reading:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pz13Lg2/1/

```
var a = [3,6,2,7,8,10,43];

a.retrieveNeighbour = function (needle) {
    if (this.indexOf(needle) == -1) {
        return {
            right: null,
            left: null
        }; 
    }
    else {
        return {
            left: (this[this.indexOf(needle)-1] != undefined) && this[this.indexOf(needle)-1],
            right: (this[this.indexOf(needle)+1] != undefined) &&  this[this.indexOf(needle)+1]
        }
    }
};
console.log(a.retrieveNeighbour(3).right);
console.log(a.retrieveNeighbour(6).left);
console.log(a.retrieveNeighbour(93).right);
```

To retrieve the LEFT neighbour, use:

```
a.retrieveNeighbour(search).left;
```

To retrieve the right one:

```
a.retrieveNeighbour(search).right;
```

If the element does not exist inside the array, the script returns null to both left and right.

If the element exists but the property doesn't (like `a.retrieveNeighbour(3).left`) the script assign false to that value.

Tests:

[image]